# Visual studio Regex for batch replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I am trying to find and replace some chars in Visual studio 2017.
For exemple, I want to change this line:

```
rs.Fields("F1") = rs.Fields("F2"):
```

Into this line:

```
rs.Fields["F1"].Value = rs.Fields["F2"].Value;
```

So I need to replace according to this:

```
( --> [
) --> ].Value
: --> ;
```

First I select the line I want to change, then I find the chars I want to change with this regular expression:

```
([():])
```

This work fine. But I can't understand how to do the replace part properly.

Comment: What is a known part of the pattern?

Comment: Fields("something") is almost standart, but it could also be Fields(myVar).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/JaCd2r/2

Comment: Ok so I needed to group everything that is not ( ) or ;. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

**Find**: `\b(rs\.Fields)\(([^()]*)\)(\s*=\s*)(rs\.Fields)\(([^()]*)\):`
**Replace**: `$1[$2].Value$3$4[$5].Value;`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK6hxD/2)

**Details**

- `\b(rs\.Fields)` - Group 1 (later referred with `$1` from the replacement): `rs.Fields` substring (`\b` is a word boundary to match `rs` and not `rs` in, say,  `brs`)
- `\(` - a `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `(\s*=\s*)` - Group 3: a  `=` enclosed with optional whitespaces
- `(rs\.Fields)` - Group 4: `rs.Fields`
- `\(` - a `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 5: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `:` - a colon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(rs.Fields)\(([^)]*)\)(\s=\srs.Fields)\(([^)]*)\):
```

It starts by creating a Group, containing 're.Fields', followed by a left-parenthes, followed by any characters not being right-parenthes (in Group 1), followed by a right-parenthes. 
Then it creates a new group matching a White Space, followed by an equal sign and then the Whole thing repeated.

You then replace with the following:

```
$1[$2].Value$3[$4].Value
```